# Open the link generated on the button in a new tab

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button where it makes the API call and generate the URL , I want to open the URL in the new tab once I click the button.

```
<button (click)="getUrl()">Connect</button>
```

TS:

```
getUrl() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.url = 'www.google.com';
      console.log(this.url);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

what is the better way to get the URL from the API and open the link in the new tab. API may take more than 50 seconds to return the URL

[stackblitz link to edit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-54e173?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: So your code works. You consider it is not good enough and asking for a better way. Could you please state why do you consider it is not good enough? Why do you need a better way? Is it because you think the UX is bad? If this is the case you should add a progress bar/ spinner to indicating there is something working in the background and ask the user to wait. If there is other reason, please state clearly. Otherwise, there is nothing defined as a "better way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `window.open(this.url, '_blank').focus();`
like

```
getUrl() {
setTimeout(() => {
  window.open(this.url, '_blank').focus();
  this.url = 'www.google.com';
  console.log(this.url);
}, 1000);
```

}
}

Comment: Browser throws the error "Pop-Ups Blocked Error", my client don't the user to enable the blocked popup's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.open()` with target `_blank`. If that answers your question:

```
window.open(this.url, '_blank');
```

See updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f4ajeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Browser throws the error "Pop-Ups Blocked Error", my client don't the user to enable the blocked popup's.

Comment: opening URL in a new tab is users' preference in browsers' settings, if you want to avoid  "Pop-Ups Blocked Error", you need to open it in a new window instead of a new tab.